# How to write a program on student marks using function without parameter?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, function, void

How to write a program on student marks using function without parameter:

```
  #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

  void studentMarks(){

  }

  int main( int argc const char *argv[]) {

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

use below function :

```
int c = 0;

- (void)studentMarks { 
        NSLog(@"%d", c);
 }

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
       int a = 3, b = 2;
       c = a - b;
       [self studentMarks];
}
```

Comment: write some example here

Comment: what kind of example ?

Comment: student marks  ( total marks and percentage ) using functions in objective c without using parameters

Comment: void student()
{
    int  c;
    NSLog(@" %d",c);
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    int a = 3;
    int b = 2;
    int c;
    c = a-b;
    student();
    
    
}